# Erro instalação pacote "tabulizer" no R

Tags: r

Estou tentando instalar o pacote `tabulizer` no R e não estou conseguindo. Tentei também baixando diretamente do CRAN, mas também não deu certo. Tentei também instalando o `tabulizerjars` em separado, mas também não obtive sucesso.

```
========================================================
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=pt_BR.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=pt_BR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_2.1.0 usethis_1.5.1 

=======================================================================
> # Instala pacote extrai tabela de pdf
> install.packages("tabulizer", dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘/home/jairo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘tabulizerjars’

tentando a URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tabulizerjars_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 10902674 bytes (10.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 10.4 MB

tentando a URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tabulizer_0.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1047758 bytes (1023 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 1023 KB

* installing source package ‘tabulizerjars’ ...
** package ‘tabulizerjars’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
* installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tabulizerjars’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tabulizerjars', details:
  call: NULL
  error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: impossível carregar objeto compartilhado '/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: não é possível abrir arquivo compartilhado: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
Erro: loading failed
Execução interrompida
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/jairo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tabulizerjars’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tabulizerjars’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘tabulizerjars’ is not available for package ‘tabulizer’
* removing ‘/home/jairo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tabulizer’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tabulizer’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpSzF9Hj/downloaded_packages’
```

Answer (score 1):

Tive uma pequena epopeia para instalar esse pacote no meu computador. Primeiro eu atualizei o meu java. Depois tive que instalar o pacote `rJava`. Para instalar o tabulizer fui direto no R, sem ser através da IDE (utilizo o RStudio) e inicializei como administrador. Só então utilizei o `install.packages("tabulizer", dependencies = TRUE)`.

Não sei exatamente como seria no seu caso, pois vc utiliza um sistema operacional diferente do meu, mas deixei o passo a passo do que eu fiz, pois pode servir de orientação para você adaptar para a sua situação.

Comment: Atualizei o Java, mas na instalação do rJava já deu erro...

checking whether Java run-time works... ./configure: line 3766: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
no
configure: error: Java interpreter '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java' does not work
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’

Comment: Me parece que ele não está encontrando o java na sua máquina, ou não possui privilégio para acessá-la. Reveja os privilégios do usuário que está tentando instalar o pacote.

Comment: Já estava com os privilégios... não consegui mesmo. Na verdade não sei como resolver. Mas muito obrigado pelas ajudas e apoio.